# Vue.js Fontawesome free brand icons couldn't be found

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, font-awesome

I want to implement the Facebook logo in my vue.js app.
I already got other icons from fontawesome which are working fine.
But if I use the fontawesome free brands I got the following error in the console:

[image]

This is my implementation:

**main.js**

```js
/* import the fontawesome core */
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'

/* import specific icons */
import { faPlus } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { faFacebook } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'

/* import font awesome icon component */
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'

/* add icons to the library */
library.add(faPlus)
library.add(faFacebook)

createApp(App)
    .component("font-awesome-icon", FontAwesomeIcon)
    .use(store)
    .use(router)
    .use(CKEditor)
    .mount('#app')
```

**Home.vue**

```html
<template>
    <div class="social-media">
      <font-awesome-icon icon="facebook" />
      <font-awesome-icon icon="plus" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

The Icon plus will be rendered. But the facebook logo not.
I already checked the `node_modules` folder if fontaewsom-free-brands is there. The folder is available and also the `faFacebook.js`:

```js
'use strict';
Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });
var prefix = 'fab';
var iconName = 'facebook';
var width = 512;
var height = 512;
var aliases = [62000];
var unicode = 'f09a';
var svgPathData = 'M504 256C504 119 393 8 256 8S8 119 8 256c0 123.8 90.69 226.4 209.3 245V327.7h-63V256h63v-54.64c0-62.15 37-96.48 93.67-96.48 27.14 0 55.52 4.84 55.52 4.84v61h-31.28c-30.8 0-40.41 19.12-40.41 38.73V256h68.78l-11 71.69h-57.78V501C413.3 482.4 504 379.8 504 256z';

exports.definition = {
  prefix: prefix,
  iconName: iconName,
  icon: [
    width,
    height,
    aliases,
    unicode,
    svgPathData
  ]};

exports.faFacebook = exports.definition;
exports.prefix = prefix;
exports.iconName = iconName;
exports.width = width;
exports.height = height;
exports.ligatures = aliases;
exports.unicode = unicode;
exports.svgPathData = svgPathData;
exports.aliases = aliases;
```

Now I am wondering why in the `faFacebook.js` is the prefix set on `fab` and the error message is showing that the icon facebook with prefix `fas` is not found.

Does anyone know how I can adjust that or what I did wrong?

Comment: I think 'facebook' in the tag is not the right name. From the FA docs it looks like you got to define it as `<font-awesome-icon icon="fa-solid fa-user-secret" />` so in the case of facebook, probably `icon="fa-solid fa-facebook"` or something like that.

Comment: @paddotk Year that was also my first intention. I tried it with `fa-solid fa-facebook` and with `fa-brand fa-facebook`, but both didn't work.

Comment: Double-check with if you haven't already: this https://fontawesome.com/search?q=facebook&m=free&s=solid%2Cbrands. If you click the icon you can see the required code. Make sure you use the same icon as the one you imported, as there are multiple Facebook icons ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `font-awesome-icon` component defaults to the `fas` prefix, but you can specify the prefix by binding an array, containing the prefix as the first element, and the icon name as the second. Make sure to use the [`v-bind`](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-bind) directive when binding the array:

```html
                   
<font-awesome-icon :icon="['fab', 'facebook']" />
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-fontawesome-facebook-icon?file=src%2FApp.vue)

Answer (score 0):

use fab as a prefix for the icon name and then try, hope this is helpful.

Comment: As indicated in the question, he's already doing this.

Comment: Unfortunately the prefix is set on `fab` but for some reason fontawesome take `fas`